# python dictionary of value has list mapping

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have dictionary of list as input

```
x={'a':[1,2,3,4,5],'b':[9,2,3,4,5]}
```

I want output like this

```
[{a:1,b:9},{a:2,b:2},{a:3,b:3},{a:4,b:4},{a:5,b:5}]
```

I spent two days for this but did not get. thank you.

Comment: Show us what you have tried in that two days!

Comment: `[{'a': a, 'b': b} for a, b in zip(x['a'], x['b'])]`…

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
l = []
for i in range(len(list(x.values())[0])):
     d = {}
     for k, v in x.items():
         d[k] = v[i]
     l.append(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
[dict(zip(x, v)) for v in zip(*x.values())]
```